# How do I display the first 2 names in an email in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-listfragment

I am planning to display first 2 names in an email in my code, such that if the email is like justin.bauer@gmail.com, I want it to recognize first name justin as Justin and second name as Bauer. I know it is possible through regular expressions, but not sure how to go about it in the simplest way possible. Here's what i got to so far:

```
String filename = listentry.getName();     // full file name
                int iend = filename.indexOf(".");
                int iend2 = filename.indexOf("."+iend);
                if (iend != -1 && iend2!= -1) {
                    String subString = filename.substring(0, iend);
                    String subString2 = filename.substring(0, iend2);
                    holder.text.setText(subString +" " + subString2);
                }
```

But this doesn't quite work as expected for the second name. Can anyone fix this or provide a cleaner code for the same?

Thanks!

Comment: `("."+iend)` what do you think that does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String filename = listentry.getName();     // full file name
String[] parts = filename.split("@");
String domain = parts[1].split("\\.")[0];
String[] names = parts[0].split("\\.");
String combinedNames = "";
for (String name : names) {
    combinedNames += firstUpper(name) + " ";
}
holder.text.setText(combinedNames + "- " + firstUpper(domain));

// "abc ABC" -> "Abc Abc"
public String firstUpper(String text) {
    return (text.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1).toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: this crashes for me with the error : FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.justice.abc, PID: 21072
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
            at com.justice.abc.visuals.ListFragment$MySimpleArrayAdapter.getView(ListFragment.java:145)

Comment: can you give me all possible format examples of the return value from `listentry.getName()` ? I thought it is always like `first.second@domain.com`

Comment: sometimes its abc@domain.com and sometimes abc.def.ghi.jkl@domain.com  ,also how do i display the domain name too? something like "abc def ghi - Domain"

Comment: thanks it works, was wondering can you modify it one last time to show the format first.second.third(whatever before @)@abc.com@domain.com such that " First Second Third - Abc " without the com showing and domain showing abc is the first domain and its the company name i want to show. and want to show the first letter as uppercase for all

Comment: updated my answer again, please mark it as answered if it does :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use split command:

```
String filename = listentry.getName();     // full file name
String[] nameParts = string.split(".");
holder.text.setText(nameParts[0] +" " + nameParts[1]);
```

Comment: this crashes for me with  
this crashes for me with the error : FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.justice.abc, PID: 21072 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 at com.justice.abc.visuals.ListFragment$MySimpleArrayAdapter.getView(ListFragment.j‌​ava:145)

Comment: it also displays the boolean value false if its 3 letters like a.b.c@something.com